# I want to check if any element of a list matches any element of other list Haskell

Tags: haskell

module Dominoes where

```
type Domino = [(Int, Int)]
type Hand = Domino
type Board = Hand
type End = Board


dominoes :: Domino
dominoes = [(x, y)| x <- [0..6], y <- [x..6]]

amount_to_take = 7

hand :: Domino -> Domino
hand x  = take amount_to_take x
```

I want to check if any element of Domino matches with any element of End. Returning true if it does and false if it doesn't

```
goesP :: Domino -> End -> Bool 
goesP (h:t) (h1:t1) 
  |   h == h1 = True
  |   t == t1 = True
  |  otherwise False
```

Comment: In Haskell, `type` makes one type a synonym for another, so they're completely interchangeable. Did you intend to make `Domino`, `Hand`, `Board` and `End` all equivalent? I feel like that must be a bug, though I've never played Dominoes so maybe I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: in a way they are all the same. but Hand only takes 7 elements of Domino.

Comment: Take a look at [`intersect`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/Data-List.html#v:intersect) and [`intersectBy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/Data-List.html#v:intersectBy) .

Comment: `\xs ys -> any (\`elem\` xs) ys`

Answer (score 2):

```
goesP :: Domino -> End -> Bool
goesP (h:t) (h1:t1)
  | h == h1 = True   -- Seems legit.
  | t == t1 = True   -- Er... this checks if the ENTIRE SUBLIST is equal.
  | otherwise False  -- Should be an equals sign here.
```

Also, what happens if either of the lists is empty? You're only matching the non-empty case.

If you want to do this "by hand" (i.e., without using existing library functions), you probably want something like this:

```
goesP :: Domino -> End -> Bool
goesP []     _ = False -- Ran out of Dominos to check.
goesP (d:ds) e = hunt d e || goesP ds e
  where
    hunt d []     = False -- Run out of Ends to check.
    hunt d (e:es) = (d == e) || hunt d es
```

If you want to do this with library functions:

```
goesP :: Domino -> End -> Bool
goesP d e = any (`elem` d) e
```

Have a go at hitting [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find out why that works.