# How to check if two lists are partially identical haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

This is my code im trying to check if a list can be paritially identical into another. It is a game of dominoes a `Domino=(Int,Int)` and a `Board = [Domino]` and an end either left or right. I'm to check if any domino goes into a board say for example can domino `(2,3)` go into board `[(3,4)(5,6)]` is should be able to go to the left end because `(2,3)` and `(3,4)` have have a similar element. Here is my code

```
goesP :: Domino -> Board -> End -> Bool

goesP (h,t) [(h1,t1)] LeftEnd
      | h==h1 || t==h1 =True
      | otherwise False
goesP (h,t) [(h1,t1)] RightEnd
      | h==t1 || t==t1 = True 
      | otherwise False
```

Comment: Please format the fragment of code that you provided (it should look `like this`). At present, it is almost unreadable. You can use backticks or four spaces of indentation to get this effect. Google for "markdown" to learn more about the syntax rules for it.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin Or just click the `help` button when editing, it'll show you all the formatting syntax.

Comment: Also, we do prefer proper grammar and spelling on this site. I edited the post for now, but please make sure you get it right yourself for future questions. As for this one, it's still not clear what you are talking about with "and an end either left or right".

Comment: More importantly, what is your question? You've given us some code, which is a start. But there's a long way between what you've written and something that will compile and work.

Comment: It looks like a new duplicate of [26415759](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415759/i-want-to-check-if-any-element-of-a-list-matches-any-element-of-other-list-haske)

Comment: `otherwise = False` add a `=`

Comment: So where are you stuck?  Explain the part that you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern-matching you're using for the board is incomplete. The `[(h1,t1)]` pattern will *only* match Boards with *one* element (a pair `(h1,t1)`).

This is the same as using the pattern `(h1,t1):[]`, ie. a list (`:`) containing the element `(h1,t1)` followed by an empty list `[]`.

If we try to run your code with the examples you gave, `(2,3)` and `[(3,4), (5,6)]` (NOTE: you need a comma between the list elements!) we will get the following:

```
goesP (2,3) [(3,4), (5,6)] LeftEnd
```

Haskell will try to match these arguments against the patterns in your definition, from top to bottom.

It will check the following pattern first:

```
goesP (h,t) [(h1,t1)] LeftEnd
```

The first and third arguments will match, by 'unifying' `h` with `2`, `t` with `3` and `LeftEnd` with `LeftEnd`, but the second will fail to match. The argument `[(3,4), (5,6)]` is 'syntactic sugar' for the list `(3,4):(5,6):[]`, whilst the pattern `[(h1,t1)]` is syntactic sugar for the list `(h1,t1):[]`. We could unify `h1` with `3` and `t1` with `4`, but there's nothing to unify `(5,6)` with.

Haskell will move on to the next possibility:

```
goesP (h,t) [(h1,t1)] RightEnd
```

The first argument will match (with `h` as `2` and `t` as `3`), but the second argument will fail for the same reason as the previous clause. The third argument will also fail to match, since `LeftEnd` and `RightEnd` are different values (but that's the point ;) ).

Haskell will then see that there are no more possibilities, so the program will crash.

To fix this, you need to change the patterns for the second arguments so that Boards with more than one Domino are handled properly.

The case for `LeftEnd` is quite easy, just change the list of one element `(h1,t1):[]` to a list of *at least one* element `(h1,t1):_` (I also added the extra `=` after `otherwise`):

```
goesP (h,t) ((h1,t1):_) LeftEnd
      | h==h1 || t==h1 = True
      | otherwise      = False
```

The case for `RightEnd` is harder, since we want to compare with the *last* element of the list, but we only have access to the *first*. In this case, we can keep your definition which checks single-element lists, but *also* add another definition which uses recursion: if the list has more than one element, remove the first element and check it again. That way, any non-empty list will eventually be broken down until it only has one element, which your existing pattern can work with (again, I've added a missing `=`):

```
goesP (h,t) [(h1,t1)] RightEnd
      | h==h1 || t==h1 = True 
      | otherwise      = False

goesP (h, t) (_:xs)   RightEnd = goesP (h, t) xs RightEnd
```

Now Haskell will match `[(3,4), (5,6)]` (which is sugar for `(3,4):(5,6):[]`) against `(h1,t1):[]`. This will fail, since the lists have different lengths. It will then match `[(3,4), (5,6)]` against `_:xs`, which will succeed, unifying `xs` with `(5,6):[]`. We then run the function again, using `xs`. This time the `(5:6):[]` *will* unify with the `(h1,t1):[]`, so we can check whether the numbers are equal or not.

Also, an observation: `goesP` is actually overly complicated. You're using "pattern guards" to choose between the value `True` and the value `False`; however, pattern guards also *require* a `Bool` to work with. In other words, code like this:

```
| h==h1 || t==h1 = True
| otherwise      = False
```

Can be read as saying "Create the `Bool` value `h==h1 || t==h1`; if it is `True`, then return `True`. If it is `False` then return `False`."

Clearly this is redundant: we can just return the value `h==h1 || t==h1`:

```
goesP (h,t) ((h1,t1):_) LeftEnd  = h==h1 || t==h1
goesP (h,t) [(h1,t1)]   RightEnd = h==h1 || t==h1
goesP (h, t) (_:xs)     RightEnd = goesP (h, t) xs RightEnd
```

UPDATE: Fixed my RightEnd code